# Testing backend API via $http in AngularJS/karma/jasmine tests?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, httpbackend, angularjs-http

How do I test my API backend using AngularJS/karma/jasmine tests?

I have tried to create the smallest test-case showing my error:

#### echo_server.py

```py
from bottle import response, route, run

@route('/echo/<echo>')
def echo_echo(echo):
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return {'echo': echo}    # Served as JSON

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

#### test/unit/apiSpec.js

```
// Should this be in `test/e2e/apiSpec.js`?
describe('echo', function () {
    var scope, http;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $http) {
        $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;    // CORS
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        http = $http;
    }));


    it("should echo from server", function () {
        scope.$apply(function () {
            var ret;
            http.get("http://localhost:8080/echo/foo")
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                             ret = data;
                         })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                           ret = data;
                       });
            console.log('ret = ' + ret);
            expect(ret.echo).toBe("foo");
        });
    });
});
```

#### Output of `karma start configs/karma.conf.js`

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.8 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Linux)]: Connected on socket m7imfgmhXdOY9JVKJh8r
LOG: 'ret = undefined'
PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Linux) echo should echo from server FAILED
    Error: Unexpected request: GET http://localhost:8080/echo/foo
    No more request expected
        at $httpBackend (~Projects/~karma-tests/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js:1178)
    ...
```

Comment: Why would you use angularJS and karma to test a backend. AngularJS and Karma are all about the front-end. You don't need a browser to send an HTTP request to a server. And angular-mocks is precisely used to mock a backend, so you can't use it to test your real backend.

Comment: Advantage of putting all my tests in the one place is that when they pass; I can deploy to staging. I.e.: keep the test-server running during all development.

Comment: I have unit tests and integration tests written in Java for my backend, unit tests written in JavaScript with Karma and e2e tests written in JavaScript with angular protractor for the angular frontend, and I can build and test everything (using gradle) with a single command. My CI server also does it at every push. Using the right tool for the right job shouldn't prevent uoi from running all the tests and only deploying if all the tests pass.

Comment: Sure, but if I'm doing only generic RESTful testing, JavaScript should be fine...

Comment: I'm not saying not to use JavaScript. Karma and angular mocks aren't appropriate though. I'm pretty sure something exists in the NodeJS ecosystem to test a RESTful backend, but I don't know it well enough to suggest something.

Comment: Oh okay, just did a quick Google Search and http://frisbyjs.com/ came up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The mentioned testing stack is not intended for use this way. The request never gets dispatched because of the `$httpMockBackend` that has been decorated on top of your original `$httpBackend`.

To allow requests to pass trough you either need to exclude `angular-mocks.js`, or specify that some urls should pass through like this:

```
angular.module('yourModule').run(function ($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/).passThrough();
}
```

Read the documentation for `$httpMockBackend` [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.%24httpBackend)

Also, your test is synchronous, and the server response is asyncronous, so it will not work as expected.

Comment: But `$httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/)` doesn't has a `.passThrough()` method ?!

Comment: $httpBackend can be used via `ngMock` or `ngMockE2E`  ..but it behaves differently. ngMockE2E has .passThrough() . You might have a look at the [differences](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-ngmock-ngmocke2e-libraries/)