# Jasmine make real data rest calls

Tags: jasmine, httpbackend

Jasmine could use $httpBackend to make fake restful calls by using

```
$httpBackend.whenGet("https://www.test.com")
            .respond({....})
```

But can I make real data calls to the server I make?

Comment: I answered a similar question to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30856793/1139752

Answer (score 0):

This is an angular question, not a jasmine one, $httpBackend is from angular.

In ngMock $httpBackend don't make a real call, but it can with ngMockE2E.
To use both together, refer to

[E2E mock $httpBackend doesn't actually passThrough for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864764/e2e-mock-httpbackend-doesnt-actually-passthrough-for-me/26992327#26992327)

or

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1434

then you can use :

$httpBackend.whenGet("https://www.test.com").passThrough();

Comment: But I got an error of Object doesn't support property or method 'passThrough' when I use passThrough in Jasmine. And it works fine with the respond.

Comment: You can check the doc here :  https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend#when

Comment: Ho my bad just realise you need ngMockE2E, not just ngMock !

Comment: I tried ngMockE2E but it still didn't work. same issue here in angular github: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2512. I'm running $httpbackend in unit tests. I'm not sure whether this cause the problem.

Comment: Did you check the end of this thread : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1434